# Pyserial for reading, writing and saving serial data for my log file in my automation script

Tags: automation, serial-port, pyserial

I am automating a module using Python on windows which has got serial com port and my aim is that when I start executing test script my scripts should be able to do following activities.

- On start of script, initialize the port details and serial object should be ready to read, write etc.. .
- During step execution of script I should be able to use the serial object to pass some commands and verify the output by reading serial logs.
- all other step verification as part of test automation.
- at the end I would like to have everything activity done on the serial port to be saved to my logfile, (like how we do manually by open serial port on putty and save the logs to a file, so do all your command execution, activity etc.. finally we have log file to analyze it)

I have tried and pretty much there but saving all the serial out put to file along with sending commands for reading writing did not work well with me.

I also tried with threading so that one thread will keep on serial.readline(), writing to file and other test step can perform serial.write() serial.read_until() etc.. commands.

But the problem with this approach is lets say I call thread for saving logs to file by serial.readline() now I perform serial.read_until('xyz') the serial logs and wait until are not happening in parallel, serial is keep on jumping between thread and serial.read_until('xyz') call, so both these function are getting truncated data.

my sample code:

```
import time
import threading
import serial


class ComPort:
    """Class for controlling comport"""

    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize class for controlling comport operation."""
        self.com_port = 9
        self.com_baud_rate = 1500000
        self.ser = serial.Serial(self.com_port, self.com_baud_rate)
        self.read_data = ''
        self.stop_reading = False
        self.ser.timeout = 0

    def read_until(self, str_to_wait):
        """."""
        print("read_until")
        self.ser.timeout = 30
        self.read_data = self.ser.read_until(expected=bytes(str_to_wait.encode(encoding='utf-8')))
        self.ser.timeout = 0
        return self.read_data

    def write_data(self, data):
        """."""
        data += "\r\n"
        self.ser.write(bytes(data.encode("utf-8")))
        print("written data to serial port")

    def save_ser_logs_to_file(self):
        """."""
        with open(r"C:\abc\serial_log_file.txt", 'w+', encoding="utf-8") as fp:

            while True:
                line = self.ser.readline()
                fp.write(line.decode("utf-8", errors="ignore"))
                if self.stop_reading:
                    self.ser.flush()
                    fp.flush()
                    break
            fp.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    cp = ComPort()
    print(f"Port: {cp.ser.name} is_open: {cp.ser.is_open}")
    cp.ser.reset_input_buffer()
    cp.ser.reset_output_buffer()
    print(cp.ser.in_waiting)

    t_1 = threading.Thread(target=ap.save_ser_logs_to_file)
    t_1.start()
    # time.sleep(2)
    a = cp.read_until("login:")  **# returns truncated half data here and half in logfile**
    print(a)
    if "login:" in a.decode("utf-8", errors='ignore'):
        ap.write_data("root")
    time.sleep(3)
    cp.stop_reading = True
    t_1.join()
```